# Cannot connect Windows 10 Home to a SAGEMCOM router

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router

I have multiple devices, phones, tablets, TVs and laptop connected to my router but one device running Windows 10 Home cannot connect. I had the problem previously as well but changing the name of the network (SSID) fixed it but not this time.

Running ipconfig /all give me the following

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi
Media state Media disconnected
Description Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230
DHCP Enabled Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled Yes
```

My network is both 2.4Ghz and 5GHz, I've never been able to connect my Windows 10 to the 5GHz network, but it has been connected to the 2.4GHz network.

SAGEMCOM

```
Software Version 3890
Hardware Version 3890
```

Comment: Are you using Intel's connection drivers? Or are you using Windows generic?

Comment: Yes that's what my machine runs, why?

Comment: ?? the question was related to what driver your wireless card is using. if you installed nothing from Intel for it, its probably windows generic. if you have an Intel icon on your task-bar that relates to wireless, you are using non-generic.